# I can't use a service in angular, error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript

I created the products component and would like to initialize the product property via a service, but I can't.
I get this error: "ERROR in Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

While if the constructor I change it like this:

```
   constructor(){
     this.product = "x";
   }
```

it works properly. I am therefore unable to successfully test using a service.
I'm using node version 14.17.6, Angular 10.0.14

products.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  product: string;
  constructor(productService: ProductService){
    this.product = productService.getProduct();
  }
 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }

}
```

product.service.ts:

```
export class ProductService{
    getProduct() : string {
      return "Learning Angular";
    }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductsComponent } from './products/products.component';
import { ProductService } from './products/product.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [ProductService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Please check out the docs: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services

Comment: i tried to follow these rules and put the service in providers(app.module.ts) to make it available everywhere.

Comment: The code you provided seems to work just fine, see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wvtumg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) Could you take a look and see if you can reproduce your problem using this? See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `@Injectable()`attribute on your service

Answer (score 1):

thank you for the support. Yesterday I shut down the pc and today restarting the server the code I posted works!